# Convolution de fonctions

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

[image]

How is equality true on the second line ? (before the final result)

Comment: It's hard to tell which equality you mean. Could you clarify which equality in particular you are having difficulty with?

Comment: It’s equality before the final result (I will change)

Comment: En raison de l'invariance de la mesure de Lebesgue: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-3(u-2t/3)^2}\,du=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-3u^2}\,du$. C'est-à-dire $\int_\mathbb{R}f(u+w)\,du=\int_\mathbb{R}f(u)\,du$ pour toute $t\in\mathbb{R}$ et pour tout $f\in L_1$.

Answer (score 1):

The last equality before the final result is a consequence of the change of variable $v = \sqrt{3}u$. The equality before that is a consequence of translation invariance: $\int_{\mathbb R}f(x+y)\,dx = \int_{\mathbb R}f(u)\,du$.

For us, $f$ is Riemann integrable, so the translation-invariance can be proved by simply changing variables $u = x+y$ in the improper Riemann integral. For general (Lebesgue) integrable functions, the translation-invariance can be proved first for indicator functions, then simple functions, then nonnegative functions by monotone convergence, and finally for integrable functions by decomposing into positive and negative parts.

Comment: Thank you, where did this translation-invariance come from ? It's a result of intuition ? Is that a no-brainer ?

Comment: @Romain44: In some sense, it is a "no-brainer" if you think of the picture involved. We are simply moving the mass (or charge) around, but not changing the total mass (or charge). However, it can be proved rigorously. I added some details in my answer.